# Can I ask question about electron configuration?

Tags: support

Is this the right place or shall I wait for the chemistry proposal?

Comment: Depends, what's the question?

Comment: I want to ask about Palladium atom. It has 18 electrons in the outer shell. Shouldn't it end with 17,1 instead?

Comment: for reference, the question has been asked now: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11042/is-palladium-an-exception

Comment: @Tobian It's me who asked the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to ask about Palladium atom. It has 18 electrons in the outer shell. Shouldn't it end with 17,1 instead?

I think that question should be fine.

A rough guideline is that questions about isolated atoms are about physics and are probably okay on this site. Questions about compounds (molecules) or mixtures are likely to be about chemistry and would probably be off-topic here. Of course that's only a rough guideline; the decision has to be made on a case-by-case basis.